# Docker nginx-auto-ssl, seup multiple web services at once

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I have a docker-compose.yml file which defines multiple services. I use nginx as a reverse proxy for those services with the auto-ssl feature from `elestio/nginx-auto-ssl` image (it's the same with `Valian/docker-nginx-auto-ssl` though). It works well when I setup only a single domain, but when I try to add more, the ssl certificates are not valid (self signed):

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

...

  nginx:
    image: elestio/nginx-auto-ssl
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ssl_data:/etc/resty-auto-ssl
    environment:
      ALLOWED_DOMAINS: 'atlas.oraxen.com, repo.oraxen.com'
      SITES: 'atlas.oraxen.com=polymath:8080; repo.oraxen.com=repo:8081'
      FORCE_HTTPS: 'false'

volumes:
  ssl_data:
```

Am I missing something?